# I Cannot create a React Native project

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I am trying to create a React Native project using this command:

```
npx react-native init
```

But the template download just stops and shows the following message:

```
× Downloading template
error Error: Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native@latest
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno -4077
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here, below "Creating a new application" title](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

If you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues:

```bash
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli
```

then

```bash
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```